# Bring some sanity to job titles by forbidding all-caps (and possibly emojis)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

There is a [job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/116991/customer-engineer-software-development-grammatech-inc) currently posted on Stack Overflow Jobs. Its title is in ALL CAPS. That makes it ugly and difficult to read.

> [image: Job title in ALL CAPS]

Is there a way to restrict that, so that the *entire* job title cannot appear in all caps? This is not a mission-critical bug, but it would be nice to have properly formatted mixed case titles that didn't look like they were screaming at you.

Comment: Mmm... client pays stackoverflow to place ads, and you want to tell the client how to construct the title for their description of the job? And the reason is "it will be good"? I think business decisions require more than "it will be good". Perhaps stackoverlow could suggest to clients that "we have many, many, developers attending the site who seem overly concerned by all-caps, lawsuits for eye-damage may be coming, you may want to reconsider that", but what else do you expect them to do? Turn away the golden shilling? Annoy the client?

Comment: That job titles should not be all caps  - because they affect the visual effect of lists and ads - seems a fairly reasonable requirement to impose on employers.

Comment: What's next, "LKING 4   DEVZ"? Here is a practical consideration: the job title gets cut off in the overview list.

Comment: O M G. The possibilities are endless! `LEAVE YOUR  JOB AND COME WORK WITH US! `

Comment: @BillWoodger If an employer advertises like that, they're harmful to the site because **they annoy** potential employees, so SO has all the more reason to not only restrict such behaviour, but probably even turn down such employers at once. They can go advertise on Quora if PR is more important to them than quality. Besides, advertisers on this site aren't allowed to use popups, blinking flash games and notifications that you've just won a free iPad either. So just because anyone pays, doesn't mean they get to tear down this site's quality and integrity.

Comment: @Siguza (and others it seems). Did you read your first sentence? GrammaTech (gotta be some irony there) should not advertise like that because they would annoy (I'll leave that) some potential employees, so their ad should be turned down? So it is not about potential employees, is it? What do you do with `PL/SQL, C, COBOL and SPARK` as a title? Just get a bit annoyed? I previously suggested that the advertiser should be advised, is that not enough for you? You want rules, rules, rules? OMG. Sorry. I mean omg.

Comment: ᵂᶦᶫᶫ ʷᵉ ᵇᶫᵒᶜᵏ ᵗʰᶦˢ﹖ Wʜᴀᴛ ᴀʙᴏᴜᴛ ᴛʜɪs? Ｈｏｗ  ａｂｏｕｔ  ｔｈｉｓ？ [Ⓣⓗⓔ ⓛⓘⓢⓣ ⓖⓞⓔⓢ ⓞⓝ⨀⨀⨀](http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=Yes%2C+there%27s+more%21)

Comment: Oh great, thanks folks, now I've been reminded of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2757035) again. A dire warning of what happens when you don't place constraints on grammatical constructs...

Comment: I'm surprised that any company who claims to be tech-focussed would use all-caps in job titles - isn't this a way of accidentally letting on that they are not familiar with basic modes of interaction on the web? Or maybe their HR author has a really loud voice...

Comment: @Siguza Well, that was a low-quality first comment then (very popular). So, no, that was not really your point. I like all the contributions which presume that there is absolutely no limit to what can go in job "titles" for the advertising. A technique of argumentation and non-logic call "Building a Straw Man". You don't care about rules, as long as there are rules that you like. That don't annoy you. "low quality" means nothing without "of what". SO using low quality pencils for their coding sheets, will that tend to drive you away.

Comment: @halfer looking at their website, even their company name, it is indeed surprising. Could even be a mistake. I'm sure if brought to their attention they'd correct it :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger -  acronyms and abbreviations as an argument that all caps should be banned is a logical fallacy of [false equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence), try again with a valid argument.

Comment: Advertiser uses techniques which a) people don't like and b) argue will deter people from responding.  The advertiser is paying for the right to advertise.  You may not *like* what they do and try to use "effectiveness" as your argument, but having placed the ad, the advertiser appears to disagree.  Which leaves you with only "I don't like it".  It is of course your *right* to not like it, but you aren't paying for the ad (or even to *read* the ad).  I don't like it either but wouldn't try to tailcoat that opinion on a supposedly "objective qualitative argument" smokescreen.

Comment: Ok, more worrying is that [support] tag... seriously!

Comment: @deltics That argument appears convincing at first blush, but if you think about it a bit harder, you'll surely realize that we do have *some* standards for what job ads need to look like. That, in fact, is the whole point of the Jobs site. Stack Overflow got into the jobs business to improve it, to make it better, to bring sanity to the frustrating and chaotic world of hunting for programming jobs. We would certainly censor titles for job postings that were offensive, spammy, or otherwise inappropriate, so why not censor for failure to follow a customary style?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson It was not an argument, it was a question. Sensibly, things that require uppercase would be immune from "uppercase hurts my eyes" bans. Like EMERGENCY EXIT and DANGER - LIFT UNDER REPAIR. But. I suspect. I guess it is my background that means I don't fear uppercase. But no, I neither fear lowercase nor mixedcase. I wonder if there is any research on this?

Comment: @Cody - because those things are are disqualified by the "House Rules".  But there is **nothing** in the "House Rules" or job posting flow that even *hints* at a more general "style guide", let alone a specific (but undefined) "Customary Style".  Maybe there should be, but in the *absence* of any such rules then (by definition) no rules have been broken.  It may be ineffective.  Then again, perhaps those caps will actually someone notice it who otherwise wouldn't, so even that is arguable.  In general I'm a big fan of people abiding by rules; not so much of rules being applied out of thin air.

Comment: As a professional commercial art and typographer of 30+ years, I can assure you that there are plenty of scientific studies and research in existence that show that ALLCAPS is harder to read than proper mixed case or all lower case.  A simple google search will prove it out.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson perhaps they should change all those warning signs? That research wasn't what I meant, I meant the inability to cope with uppercase for anything beyond a word or two. Used to be I'd write COBOL code in all upper, and rexx code in all lower. Looking at programs which didn't conform to this made code more 'difficult' to read. However, when I started not bothering to stick to one case, suddenly those same weird programs became as easy as others. Objectively vs subjectively. I wonder if the Chinese were polled.

Comment: @deltics I don't understand. That's what this question is about/proposing: establishing some "House Rules" or a "Customary Style" that the titles of job postings should be written with proper mixed-case formatting. No one is saying that rules have been broken and floggings should commence. Personally, I don't really like all this talking about rules. I think convention and common sense are sufficient here, as in most other places.

Comment: It must be programmatically possible to encapsulate every word except the first alphabetical character inside `<span>`-tags and apply `text-transform: lowercase;` on this

Comment: @OgierSchelvis Sure, but that's heavy-handed. Acronyms in particular will be nuked.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol I know it's not 100% fool-proof. You would have to determine what is a word, what is an acronym (maybe an exception dictionary for words like PHP or ASCII) and also abbreviations which are supposed to be written in all caps with periods between them should be exempt from being forced to lowercase.

Comment: I'd say allow everything and anything.  That way, when you see a company doing stupid crap this, you know they're staffed with idiots, and can therefore avoid wasting your time applying.

Comment: GrammaTech, buddy, no...
CodeSurfer and CodeSonar are too useful to have ads that yell at me...

Comment: How about a user preference to not show jobs whose titles are all caps?

Comment: @halfer Out of curiosity, would all caps be appropriate if the company was named `LoudTech` or something similar?  Considering the name, it would be difficult to determine whether it was a sign that they weren't as tech-focused as they claim, or just a self-aware marketing gimmick.

Comment: Customer engineer... that sounds like someone who designs customers.

Comment: In my experience, these all-caps titles are a sign of copy-pasted job descriptions from an internal system that doesn't allow case. The fact that it specifies "Software Development" on Stack Overflow also points to that. I'm not sure if that's a problem, but it's a sign that they aren't thinking very hard about the ad.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**This is why we offer a job flagging feature. Let us know about obnoxious titles in *any* format and we'll try to get them fixed. The original title in question here has already been improved.**

Anyway, thanks for bringing this up. As Juice said, we don't have any plans to change this functionality at this time. It's not because companies pay us. It's not because we want you to have a terrible experience. It's because a job posting is an expression of a company, and in the same way that we don't censor your profile (other than profanity and discrimination), we also don't want to censor their Job "profile" offered to you.

Having said that, we do offer guidance to companies posting Jobs with us. We advise employers on the best way to structure their listings from various angles - grammar, writing style, content, ad targeting, etc. We're a "full service" job board, if you will. We want them to succeed and we want developers to get awesome jobs. But at the end of the day, it's still up to the employers to follow that advice.

When they don't follow our advice, consider all caps, emoji, etc. an easy screener for you: if you don't like their style, you're probably unlikely to enjoy the job they offer as well.

Comment: The only thing you may argue is that successful campaigns are normally based on the quality of the ad itself. In this case the ad is a job offer and companies try to get the best employees they can, so it may be shooting themselves in the foot to use an ad that may limit your options just to be "stylish". A guidance may be in order, like "SO communities expect certain standards when communicating, here are some tips for a successful communication: ..."

Comment: @Braiam exactly, but the question I have (speaking personally) is: is it Stack Overflow's job to try and censor them? Should we try and make them into something they aren't? That would mean they'd misrepresent their all-caps and emoji loving selves to the users, and that wouldn't be ideal (bait and switch).

Comment: Well, we do reject questions outrightly that are written in all caps, do that means that we "censor" them? No, of course. If anything, the house owner is the one that dictates what is allowed in their house, the one that doesn't like it may just not enter it, right?

Comment: @Braiam questions are not the same as ads / jobs. A bit of a straw man argument (as is mine re: profiles), but I get your point. It's an interesting discussion that I can see either side of.

Comment: @Braiam We advise employers on the best way to structure their listings from various angles - grammar, writing style, content, ad targeting, etc. We're a "full service" job board, if you will. We want them to succeed and we want developers to get awesome jobs. But at the end of the day, it's still up to the employers to follow that advice.

Comment: @AdamLear if they shoot themself in the foot, at least you tried, eh? :P

Comment: To this I'll add that we don't even block all-caps titles *on Stack Overflow*. Maybe someone programs exclusively in FORTRAN on a 1960s-era teletype. [We do warn you against it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/132Ej.png), but if you're determined to shoot yourself in the foot... Well, you got 10 toes for a reason I guess.

Comment: There are... quite a few nonsensical job titles (I've listed a few [in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=jobs&user=237685&room=)). I understand your position, but if Jobs is really going to be a "better" job searching website, shouldn't it start with improving job titles?

Comment: @Haney I flagged [this job](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/119173) for the all CAPS and got the response as [this doesn't contravene our terms of service.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD1UN.png).

Answer (score -14):

Right now we have no plans to force companies into "No all Caps compliance". We can make suggestions, and we do, but we're not going to turn away customers because of it.

There are a lot of rules that we do enforce. Important ones such as spam and being upfront about being a recruiter or offering real remote work. I (and many of us) agree a title in all caps isn't great, but we have lots of battles to fight, and this isn't going to be one right now.

Comment: Why not?  Isn't the whole point of SO Jobs to improve the developer's experience of looking for a job?  Allowing formatting tactics like this seems counter to that desired experience.

Comment: How is having a title in all caps "ruining the experience"? I'm agreeing it looks dumb, but not to the point of forcing customers to do something they don't want to do. We have several rules that we enforce that are more important to the community.

Comment: This addresses the no caps, what about the other items brought up in the comment.  Are "non-standard" characters are permitted?  Are emjoi's allowed?  What about zalgo text?  I realize some of the examples provided were extreme, but they can certainly be a lot worse than all caps

Comment: If you're not fighting this battle "right now", why not mark it deferred rather than declined?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Honestly, not sure if that's ever some up. We'd probably make a decision on a case by case basis.

Comment: @davidism Fair enough. I can't say we never will. I've changed the tag.

Comment: While all caps doesn't "ruin the experience" I'd argue that the smaller details are just as important as the big rules in making something that is for developers first.  Pretty sure recruiters who don't disclose that they are don't *want* to disclose that, but you force them to, so the "don't force customers to do something they don't want to do" doesn't really hold up.

Comment: @Juice tangent to the feature request - if a member of the community were to flag such posts - is that something that the jobs team would deem useful and maybe if necessary change the casing/remove unnecessary characters if present?

Comment: Seems like the advertising system could automatically convert all-caps to title case. Why does this have to be a battle? It could just be built into the platform. "Code is law," or some such thing.

Comment: @JonClements Yes. That would help.

Comment: @psubsee2003 if a recruiter ever mentions TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y in a job ad, I *might* actually read it ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Would such an ad be parseable with regex?

Comment: @dorukayhan depends. Are you [Tom Christiansen](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-4/)?

Comment: @dorukayhan yes, of course! `(?>\P{M}\p{M}+)+` should do a fine job :)

Comment: @NathanArthur "Automatically" converting all-caps (or no-caps) text to **correct** title case is rather harder to get right than people imagine who haven't attempted it. Humans get better results. For one thing, you need a stop list of domain-specific words that must always be in all caps, like TCP, GUI, or SMB. Those won't be in a regular dictionary. You also need to distinguish the same word used as s short proposition, which isn't capitalized unless it's the first or last word in a title, from the case when that same word is used as an adverb, in which case it normally does get capitalized.

Comment: @tchrist Point taken.