# Can we prevent the use of ALL CAPS in job adverts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I just stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/freenet-group) (***german***) job posting, and noticed that the benefits are displayed in ALL CAPS, something that - in my opinion - drastically reduces the readability.

The benefits are also displayed on the "ad" while browsing Stack Overflow, also with ALL CAPS.

Can we prevent this from happening? It looks ugly, it's really not "nice" to read through, and the benefits get cut off 3/4 through when displayed as an ad.

Or, in case the answer is no, can we at least prevent the benefits being displayed with ALL CAPS in the ads?

Comment: But they ride hoverboards around the office! They're legally obliged to use caps lock, being that cool and all!

Comment: @deceze BUT I DON'T LIKE BEING SCREAMED AT WHEN BROWSING POTENTIAL JOBS! :(

Comment: BUT THEY'RE AWESOME BENEFITS! – OK, seriously, I just watched that video and cringed pretty hard. Looks very much like they're trying way too hard there.

Comment: sides the point but the video is a cringefest.

Comment: The benefits are actually nice, but caps... And I cannot watch the video right now, not sure if that's a good or bad thing :)

Comment: "GESUNDHEITSPRÄVENTION" – Uhm, not sure I actually want that?! 

Comment: Oh lmao. I missed that. Wow. Well, that ain't good...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328091/bring-some-sanity-to-job-titles-by-forbidding-all-caps-and-possibly-emojis

Comment: @Des Did you mean to tag this with [status-deferred](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred)?

Comment: @dorukayhan No. I just noticed a typo in my answer and updated it. We will not be implementing validation on benefits. We're treating this as support issue. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @Seth Some of the benefits...HEALTH PROVENTION not so much.

Comment: Why stop at just ads? Why not prevent all caps everywhere? It looks unprofessional and it reduces readability. That lowers the quality of the site overall. Further, can anyone provide a counter example of when it is actually helpful to have a post of any kind that is in all caps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the report! Validation on benefits isn't something we will implement at this time ([see this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328091/bring-some-sanity-to-job-titles-by-forbidding-all-caps-and-possibly-emojis)).  We've flagged the jobs associated with this company so that our support team can reach out.

Comment: While I understand not having a validation that *requires* employers to not use all-caps, it seems it might be a good idea to have a check for the use of all caps in regular text which either A) Puts up a notice to the person entering the job listing saying something like "It appears you are using ALL-CAPS in your posting. Our users often respond negatively (link) (link) to the use of ALL-CAPS for regular text, which they read as yelling (i.e. all-caps is fine for acronyms). It is suggested that you don't use ALL-CAPS for regular words"; or B) alerts your support team to check the post.

Comment: Hey @Des - can you also please have a look at the ads from [this company](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?cl=Analytics%20Fire) as they have used ALL CAPS on their job title, which is highly annoying when displayed in the jobs advertising rectangle.