# Clickbait titles in job advertisements

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

Advertisements on Stack Overflow are usually the only place I know of where they are non-intrusive and still more or less relevant. I encountered this job ad for a few days where a particular company in my country (I deliberately only show the company name in the image) advertises with clickbait job titles.

Clickbait rarely describes anything accurately and is mostly used to drive clicks to increase ad revenue. It seems pretty counterproductive in this case, and it personally annoys me to see clickbait links on Stack Overflow. It makes Stack Overflow look like one of those many cash grab websites without any depth or real content out there.

I know I can block companies, and I have done so in this case, but I would like to ask if Stack Overflow can vet these kinds of advertisements and prevent these kind of job adverts from showing in the first place.

[image: A clickbaity company]

N.B. Apparently someone flagged this question as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328091). While the answers may or may not be relevant, this question is obviously not about caps in a job title and should thus not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: On the one hand, I agree - this seems unprofessional and unbecoming of a company wanting to hire.  On the *other* hand, it *is* Friday today (in the States), and I would like to know why the C++ vacancy almost died...

Comment: I mean... if they didn't allow these through, you wouldn't have known that they do this kind of stuff and therefore wouldn't have blocked them...

Comment: True. On the other hand, it doesn't necessarily mean the company is a bad apple I should avoid at all costs if some HR person believes driving clicks to their job offers this way is the way to go. Those are not the people I would generally work with. Then again, I would need to drive cross-country every day to work a job with a language I haven't touched since university. There are probably better companies out there if I want to switch jobs.

Comment: On the other hand, you would end up working with the sort of coworkers who would respond to a clickbait job ad.

Comment: I've never used Jobs but isn't there an option to flag/report advertisements or companies?

Comment: To me these read like an attempt at humour, not as *actual* click bait. Maybe because it’s a Dutch company and I am Dutch? I know from experience that not everyone recognises Dutch humour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, I am Dutch too. I don't really see how this is funny though.

Comment: I don’t find them funny either, but I can see that they were intended to be.

Comment: `This C++ vacancy almost died` is definitely humour.

Comment: I think we don't need jobs to be vetted before they are posted because that just doesn't seem feasible to me. We do have the option to report job postings. The major thing we need is official guidance on if we should report these postings as inappropriate. In my opinion, we probably should, but these postings are company-moderated, not community-moderated, so I'd like SE to take a stance on this.

Comment: Its clearly no funny enough and therefore does not deserve any sort of longevity. It needs to die.

Comment: I almost died once. Wasn't funny. I feel for the vacancy person, whoever they are.

Comment: Regarding your edit stating that this isn't a duplicate, the reason I flagged it as such was that the answers are basically the same thing. From the accepted answer: *It's because a job posting is an expression of a company, and in the same way that we don't censor your profile (other than profanity and discrimination), we also don't want to censor their Job "profile" offered to you*

Comment: I think that the title of **this** question should have been something along the lines of **"See how stack overflow advertisers are blatantly trying to ..."** (with the intentional "..." at the end). What a missed opportunity :-/

Comment: @Marco13 Or "The Shocking New Secret Strategy Stack Job Recruiters Won't Tell You..."

Answer (score 26):

Since nobody else has said it yet, I would argue this should be stopped.

The reason is that the only incentive I can see not to do this is if a HR department thinks it is more economic to let the criteria of "the right people haven't happened to see this" (which is overcome by clickbait) decide their initial filter, rather than doing whatever initial filter they like. That filter could still be automated & cheap, and yet yield better results in their eyes.

*(Addendum: the other possible reason to stop this which I missed is that it might actually decrease applicants. But some HR/PR departments appear to think it works, which may or may not indicate they have numbers to support this, so this is hard to rely on)*

Based on that, at least for bigger companies with more ambitious HR departments I can't see why they *wouldn't* all eventually go down this road if it's not policed.

So unless StackOverflow wants a notable amount of job ads to become annoying clickbait - I can see that some people might just not care - then this shouldn't be allowed. But that's just my opinion of course.

Comment: "Since nobody else has said it yet, I would argue this should be stopped." Well, nobody except the OP...

Answer (score 18):

This is sarcasm. A [**parody**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parody) of clickbait titles. This is their take at humor.

*Actual* clickbait would have *baited* you. This already says what it is. It's a C++ vacancy. With a funny title to get noticed in the crowd of boring "C++ Developer" titles.

Granted, sarcasm is banned by the CoC, but do we really need to squeeze the last bit of fun and humor out of SO?

Answer (score 6):

While I share your disdain for clickbait titles, this particular case is tricky.

Looking through their listings, it’s clear that this is the company attempting to put some humour into their listings – whether it’s actually funny or not is a different story. Looking at the job description on these listings, they all contain something along the lines of:

[image: screenshot of start of job description]

What follows is actually a pretty thorough and relevant description of the role, the skills they’re looking for, and info about the company. Their listings aren’t misguiding users or maliciously trying to get users to apply.

Is this effective? Well, it depends. It comes off cheeky at best, off putting and unprofessional at worst. Using humour in job descriptions is always a dicey subject since it can easily backfire. As some of the folks here pointed out, it gives you a glimpse into the company culture. Some users will find it funny, others won’t.

Is this malicious or SPAM? No, I wouldn’t go that far. It looks like they’ve put in the effort to write a comprehensive listing and attempted to stand out from the crowd (for better or for worse). There’s nothing misleading in the job description and the roles are legit.

Is this an epidemic? Absolutely not. We don’t see any evidence that clickbait titles are proliferating.

And if this just rubs you the wrong way? Dismiss the company or listing. You’re always in control of the content we show you, and the feedback helps us get better at filtering and targeting content.

Answer (score 2):

From a Job advertisement perspective - I think it's fine.

Not because I like clickbait, but because their choice of title is representative of their company and culture.

I would have had the same reaction as you, this company is advertising itself as being highly unprofessional and as I look down on people who click on this sort of stuff (let alone the people who create it), I can tell from this advertisement that this job isn't meant for me.

Being able to discern when you aren't going to be a fit for a company is a very important part of the job hunting/advertising process.

---

The thing that's not so fine about it is that StackOverflow is a question/answer site. It happens to do job stuff on the side, but that's not why people come here most of the time, if at all.

This means that people who come here for their quick copy-paste answer are going to see stuff like this on the side, and **not realise that this message is representing a company other than StackOverflow**. In other words, these ads make StackOverflow itself look unprofessional.

Therefore I think it's in StackOverflow's interest to discourage this sort of advertising.

Answer (score -8):

I don't think how it is harmful for any member of the community.

You are still free to look at the job advert details or not, and provided this an actual job position advert behind this, I don't think there is any concern to have or action to take.

The companies should have some freedom for creativity, as already noted, and if some counter-productiveness should arise, this is on their side, in my opinion.

If applicants don't like this, then they should not apply. That is enough for me to *not* choose them, since I hate most ads and clickbaits personnaly (even though it looks more like a humorous attempt)

Currently, I doubt that a "click bait job advertisement disease spread" is ongoing.

Comment: Why is too many applicants ever bad? You can still write the worst automated filter to sift through them, and it'll probably give you better results (or at least not worse) than letting the completely random `haven't clickbaitily caught attention of the right people` criteria filter it for you. How is there any sort of incentive for companies to not all start doing this once they see it's not policed?

Comment: @J.T. "How is there any sort of incentive for companies" -> I'm pretty confident that a lot (if not most people) that want a job will prefer clicking on a more descriptive advertisement. And, while I'm thinking about this, I think they risk also to have too few applicants. Anyway, I would not like to click on this ad. That will be the incentive of stopping this. Also, it looks like [slippery slope fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slippery_slope).

Comment: Well, the fallacy entirely depends on whether I'm wrong. This is hard to know without knowing the click numbers, but HR departments surely will do A/B tests so if this works, why *wouldn't* they expand on it? And given where the whole advertisement industry ended up as a whole, is it really so wrong to be cautious here?

Comment: Note : I edited out the "too many applicants" example, as I don't know the numbers here.

Comment: Right. The numbers might be key though. Or the practice spreading, because that could indicate positive numbers exist. Because if it works, it will keep happening and then it's entirely up to StackOverflow to decide if we actually want this. (And I personally am really not a fan)

Comment: @J.T. I think this is right to raise the subject as a question on meta, and give opinion on the situation. On one side, you are right to be cautious, and I'm merely giving an opinionated answer here. Some actual insight from SO team with numbers would be interesting.

Comment: What does `we have a new most liked instagram post` tell me about a job opening? Nothing, that's what. Cool, you guys have an instagram account. So does *everyone.* (There's also no reason why your company having a new most-liked post means anything for me getting a new job, much less one in C++)